# ProjectQ- In which part of the controlled gate object are the control bits scored

Tags: simulation, quantum-computing

I've been trying to decompose the projectQ objects and I could manage to decompose non controlled gates, and daggered gates. But I noticed that 
the object of a controlled version of a gate is the exact same as the object of that gate.

The code generating these objects:

```
  eng = MainEngine()
  q = eng.allocate_qubit()
  p = eng.allocate_qubit()
  c = eng.allocate_qubit()
  X | q
  CNOT | (p,q)
```

This is the XGate object

```
{'_control_qubits': [],
 '_engine': <__main__.MainEngine object at 0x7fc323e4d198>,
 '_qubits': ([<projectq.types._qubit.WeakQubitRef object at 0x7fc30b0a3ef0>],),
 'gate': <projectq.ops._gates.XGate object at 0x7fc316778048>,
 'tags': []}
```

And this is the CNOT gate, which is the same as ControlledGate(XGate)

```
{'_control_qubits': [],
 '_engine': <__main__.MainEngine object at 0x7fc323e4d198>,
 '_qubits': ([<projectq.types._qubit.WeakQubitRef object at 0x7fc30b0b1080>],),
 'gate': <projectq.ops._gates.XGate object at 0x7fc316778048>,
 'tags': []}
```

Both have no control qubits and it seems like the control gates lost the control qubit.

Any idea on where the control qubit is stored?

Comment: It might be better to ask this on http://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/, there are probably more people who are familiar with ProjectQ there than in general SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control qubits are only added to the command after it is received by the `ControlEngine` further down the chain after the `MainEngine`. For implementation details see "3.2.1 Implementation of meta instructions" [here](https://doi.org/10.3929/ethz-b-000322770).

To implement a testing engine such as this one, that can be used to check that indeed control qubits are added right after the `MainEngine`, you could do the following:

```py
test_eng = Testing(BasicEngine) # Or CommandPrinter
eng = projectq.MainEngine(engine_list=[test_eng])
```